# Surface integral check

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

If $S$ is a sphere with radius $r$ and centre $(a,b,c)$, and I want the surface integral of:

$$\mathbf{F}=\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$
over S, is this correct:

$$\int_S\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}=\int_V\text{div}\,\mathbf{F}\,\mathrm{d}V=3\int_V\mathrm{d}V=4\pi r^3$$
Because the volume of a sphere is $4\pi r^3/3?$

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct, you can also calculate the integral directly without using the divergence theorem. The surface normal is $\mathbf{n}=\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r}$ where $\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)$ so $\mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{n}=r$ and since the surface area is $4\pi r^2$ one gets the same answer.